# How can I input multiple characters into the array of an object using istream object? (and \0 as sentinel value. My code below will not work)

Tags: c++, user-input, istream

The following code will not work. Can someone please give me an idea as to why? This is my first time posting on here, so I'm sorry if my question seems to vague...

```
istream &operator>>(istream &in, CharacterSet &s)
{
   for (int x = 0; x < ARRSIZE; x++)
   {
      s.charArray[x] = false;
   }

   char myChar = '\0';

   do
   {
      in >> myChar;

      if (myChar >= 32 && myChar <= 126)
      {
         s.charArray[myChar - 32] = true;
      }

   } while (myChar != '\0');

   return in;
}
```

Comment: You should probably use the character constants (e.g. 'a' or '1') isntead of magic numbers (especially since afaik C++ doesn't mandate ascii encoding, it also makes the code clearer)

Comment: @Borgleader thank you for your response. This is a member function of a class. It's goal is to set an array of bool values to true or false. True if the char is valid. Only printable characters can be stored in the array so I have an array with 95 elements, set to false, and they are set to true if the user inputs them. Space is array element 0 will the ~ character is the last in the array. What do you mean by magic numbers?

Comment: @Borgleader was referring to lines such as `myChar >= 32`. It should be `myChar >= ' ' && myChar <= '~'`.

Comment: What does "will not work" mean? What is it doing wrong? Are you sure the input stream has a null byte? Why not just read until EOF?

Comment: @JohnMarkCaguicla Oh I see, thank you for that. It makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Barmar I mean that it's not storing the values inside of the array of characters which is a private member of my CharacterSet class. Will EOF work if it is reading from user input and not a file? Thank you all for your help so far.

Comment: What array of characters? `s.charArray[]` appears to be an array of booleans, which is indexed by the character code - 32.

Comment: If you're reading from user input, EOF is signaled with Ctl-d on Unix, Ctl-z on Windows. How were you expecting them to input `\0`?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, sorry about that, I meant array of booleans. I was expecting them to enter characters as follows: @ # % ! & \0    and then for the program loop to exit once it got to the \0...Is that wrong?

Comment: Escape sequences are not processed in user input, only in program literals. Typing `\0` doesn't enter a null character. It just enters the backslash and 0 characters.

Comment: @Barmar Ahh that's one problem. Thank you for that. I cannot think of a sentinel value to stop the loop, at least a non printable value the user can enter. Any recommendations to exit the loop once the user is done entering characters?

Comment: You could read line by line with `getline()`, and have them enter a blank line as the sentinel.

Comment: @Barmar That would require them to hit enter after each character right?

Comment: No. You read the line, then loop over the characters in the line.

Comment: Then read another line, and so on until they enter a blank line.

Comment: istream &operator>>(istream &in, CharacterSet &s)
 {
 
     for (int x = 0; x < ARRSIZE; x++)
     {
        s.charArray[x] = false;
     }
 
 
     string inputString;
 
     in >> inputString;
 
     for (int x = 0; x < inputString.length(); x++)
     {
         if (inputString[x] >= ' ' && inputString[x] <= '~')
         {
             s.charArray[inputString[x] - 32] = true;
         }

     }

 
     return in;
 } @Barmar Why won't this work? It only sets the value to true for the first character in the string. :/

Comment: Don't put long code in comments, it's practically impossible to read without formatting.

Comment: Try using a debugger to see why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Read line by line and then loop over the characters in the line. Use a blank line as the sentinel.

```
istream &operator>>(istream &in, CharacterSet &s) {
    for (int x = 0; x < ARRSIZE; x++) {
        s.charArray[x] = false;
    }

    std::string line;
    while (in.getline(line) && line != "") {
        for (char myChar: line) {
            if (isprint(myChar)) {
                s.charArray[myChar - ' '] = true;
            }
        } 
    }
    return in;
}
```